# Christmas Hats!!! C'mon Expats!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Hats are now active on expats!

[Our very own leaderboard is available here](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/expatriates.stackexchange.com).

If you're wondering what the hats are, or what you have to do to get them, check out the [winterbash page of hats](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/).

The easiest way to get a hat? Probably to upvote a post on the app, or add a bounty.

Also hop into the chat for discussions on finding more hats!

So many of the activities required to get hats benefit our site, so it's beneficial to all :D

Comment: The are already ended, hey.

Comment: @nicael the post was written before Christmas ;)

Comment: I know, but no longer the hats are there :)